# how to select list of another list in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this class

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

and I fill my list by this method,

```
private static void FillLists()
{
    List<Student> lststudent = new List<Student>();
    lststudent.Add(new Student { Name = "Arash", Grade = 12 });
    lststudent.Add(new Student { Name = "Kamran", Grade = 13 });
    lststudent.Add(new Student { Name = "koroush", Grade = 16 });

    List<Student> lststudent2 = new List<Student>();
    lststudent2.Add(new Student { Name = "Arman", Grade = 18 });
    lststudent2.Add(new Student { Name = "Aria", Grade = 10 });
    lststudent2.Add(new Student { Name = "Daryoush", Grade = 20 });

    List<List<Student>> students = new List<List<Student>>();
    students.Add(lststudent);
    students.Add(lststudent2);
}
```

my question is How can I get a list of the `grade > 15` students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an easy and short solution, try this:

```
var st = students.SelectMany (s => s).Where(s=>s.Grade>15).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    students.Add(lststudent.Where(s=>s.Grade>15).ToList());
    students.Add(lststudent2.Where(s=>s.Grade>15).ToList());
```

with one line of code

```
students.Add(lststudent.Where(s=>s.Grade>15).Concat(lststudent2.Where(s=>s.Grade>15)).ToList());
```

as in  comments you  can change your code to  have only one `lstStudent` and  filter it as  you  need this something like this

```
 var studentWith15grade =     lststudent.Where(s=>s.Grade>15).ToList();
```

Comment: problem is you need to change the code every list you add :) ,, ex :  adding lststudent3 will need another change to code ..

Comment: @KcDoD you have right but I think the OP is a beginner so we could go step by  step with him

Comment: your solution is good but @KcDoD's right when i add lststudent3 i should to change my code , i want to select of students list ,,,, list students.Where(...

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM please take a look at Muctadir's anwser i want like this

Comment: @HoseinMasoomi  no  this  will  be repetitive task  as there is no need for SelectMany and will make an allocation on  the heap twice

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM Could you explain how `SelectMany` "allocates on the heap twice"?

Comment: @Default as selectMany uses delegate and where uses a delegate  and by definition a delegate is a reference type so it will be instantiated undercover twice this is just a guess

Comment: well, not really, it simply foreaches over the list and the sublist and calls the resultSelector. It doesn't instantiate it again. [Check here for reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,bc79a642e00b8681,references)

Comment: However, since your examples calls `ToList`, new `List`s are created, i.e. I believe that your code would create more on the heap than the use of `SelectMany`. The difference in performance is probably **insignificant** though. Readability is a different thing.

Comment: @Default yes I know the source reference even if you put a breakpoint and you try  to step through ".Net Framework source stepping" you  can't see it because the compiler does it automatically for you

Comment: @Default check  this link Steven answer ``http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674593/performance-concern-when-using-linq-everywhere``

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `foreach()` for  `List<List<Student>> students`

```
List<Student> Filtered = new List<Student>(); // Filtered list with students with grade > 15

// Foreach List<Student> in students list
foreach (List<Student> mylist in students)
{
     // Foreach student class in selected list
     foreach (Student student in mylist)
     {
          // check grade > 15 and add if so to filtering list
          if (student.Grade>15)
          {
               Filtered.Add(student);
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge lists into one:

```
var finalList = new List<Student>(lststudent);
finalList.AddRange(lstStudent2);
// then you can query on finalList 
var result = finalList.Where(s => s.Grade > 15);
```